# how to remove `<lambda>` after groupby agg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame i would like to perform `mode` operation in groupby function. I did that using following snippet,

```
df=df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg([lambda x:x.mode()[0]]).reset_index()
```

After that df contains **lambda** in my data frame as a first row.

Input:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   a1   b1   c1   d1
1   a1   b1   c1   d1
2   a1   b1   c2   d2
3   a1   b2   c2   d2
4   a1   b2   c2   d2
5   a1   b2   c3   d3
```

Output

```
  col1 col2     col3     col4
            <lambda> <lambda>
0   a1   b1       c1       d1
1   a1   b2       c2       d2
```

I have two questions:

1.Why am i getting this record?

2.how to remove this? I mean is there any pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[]` from `agg` for avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df=df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg(lambda x:x.mode()[0]).reset_index()
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   a1   b1   c1   d1
1   a1   b2   c2   d2
```

Comment: @jezrael-could you explain your answer

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - I find better answer, so remove old one.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add the parameter `as_index=False`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a1', 'b1', 'c'], ['a1', 'b1', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c']])

res = df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False)[2].agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0])

#     0   1  2
# 0  a1  b1  c
```